# exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to fill a `ComboBox` after I insert a value in another `TextBox`. It keeps returning:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

```
public void carrega_status()
{
    string sql2 = "select * from tb02_alarme WHERE tb02_desc =" + txtdescala + " ;";
    SqlConnection conn1 = Conexao.ObterConexao();
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, conn1);
    DataTable resultado = new DataTable();
    resultado.Clear();
    txtstatus.DataSource = null;
    da2.Fill(resultado);
    txtstatus.DataSource = resultado;
    txtstatus.ValueMember = "tb02_class";
    txtstatus.DisplayMember = "tb02_class";
    txtstatus.SelectedItem = "";
    txtstatus.Refresh();

}
```

The error presents itself on `da2.Fill(resultado);`.

Comment: What does the result of `sql2` look like? (quotes?)

Comment: Use parameters instead.

Comment: Well, if `txtdescala` contains `,` you'll have such an error

Comment: You should be using SQLParamters - never StringConcaction - outside of early learning examples. Or you are the other end of this discussion: https://xkcd.com/327/ | And if you do use concaction, at least look at the final string!

Comment: @shar You're probably missing the single quotes necessary for a string value: `string sql2 = "select * from tb02_alarme WHERE tb02_desc =" + txtdescala + " ;";` try changing to this: `string sql2 = "select * from tb02_alarme WHERE tb02_desc = '" + txtdescala + "' ;";`

Comment: Your problem is a warning sign that should be taken very seriously.  If you can't control what the contents of `txtdescala` is, you open yourself to a SQL injection attack.  Someone could insert a statement that can delete your table or your database or other dangerous things.  Answer: use parameters.

Comment: @Caramiriel the result is "a"

Comment: @shar just "a"?

Comment: @BugFinder yes, it's just a test aplication

Comment: Well "a" is not valid sql - im not too surprised its complaining but that doesnt match the error you have shown

Comment: @shar There is **no** reason to not use parameterized queries, regardless of the size or complexity of an application. They are natively supported, immediately solve this kind of problem, and completely solve one of the biggest sources of security compromises in our industry. Look up parameterized queries and implement them.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution that works with me :

```
    string sql2 = "select * from tb02_alarme WHERE tb02_desc ='" + txtdescala + "' ;";
```

Comment: Except that if the OP continues with this, they're open to SQL Injection attacks. Even for test applications, it's worth using SQL parameters *right* from the start IMO.

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to leave yourself open to SQL injection. Especially if you are just learning, you should learn the correct way from the start - instead of learning the hard way. 
[Here is a simple tutorial on how to do this.](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

People can answer your question all they want, but it won't help you in the long run. With all the comments telling you to use parameters, you should really heed the warning, as all of these people are the experts trying to help you!